# new div not accepting text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text

I created a new div with a value input by the user, this works fine (I tested this with background-color, width, and height properties and it works perfectly)

However I cannot seem to get the new div to accept the text value. I tried using both `newName.html('hello)` and `newName.text('hello')` but neither worked. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
names.push(newName);
var newName = document.createElement('div')
newName.setAttribute('id', newName);
document.body.appendChild(newName);
newName.text('hello');
$(newName).css('position','absolute')
$(newName).css('top','100px');
$(newName).css('left','100px');
```

Comment: you need to wrap it into jquery `$(newName).text('hello');`

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you adding the `newName` to an array before creating it?

Answer (score 3):

`text` and `html` are jQuery methods. You need to do

```
$(newName).text('text');
```

or

```
$(newName).html('<html>');
```

and with the pure Javascript

```
newName.innerText = 'text';
```

or

```
newName.innerHTML = '<html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using plain js, you need to use a `innerHTML` or `innerTEXT` to update respectively the html or text of the element.

`.html()` is a wrapper method provided by a 3rd party library, like, `jQuery`.